# Buenas, quiero que me ayuden porfa, pasa que no entiendo bien los signos en Kotlin. Eso de "?" y "!"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Aqui les dejo el codigo para que vean que si hay algo que estoy haciendo mal, mesale que tengo un error con el arrayOfNulls y arrayOf.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private fun handleUploadMessages(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    var results: Array<Uri>? = null
    try {
        if (resultCode !== RESULT_OK) {
            results = null
        } else {
            if (intent != null) {
                val dataString = intent.dataString
                val clipData = intent.clipData
                if (clipData != null) {
                    results = arrayOfNulls(clipData.itemCount)
                    for (i in 0 until clipData.itemCount) {
                        val item = clipData.getItemAt(i)
                        results[i] = item.uri
                    }
                }
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = arrayOf(Uri.parse(dataString))
                }
            } else {
                results = arrayOf(mCapturedImageUri)
            }
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    mUploadMessages!!.onReceiveValue(results)
    mUploadMessages = null
}
```

Adjunto una imagen para que lo vean mejor, en la imagen sale que tengo errores al momento de grabar en el array o estoy entiendo mal. Porfa necesito saber como podría mejorar este codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo recordar, que el ?, cuando había posibilidad de notnull

Comment: Todo el código va _como texto, con formato_. Por lo demás, tu respuesta está en la [documentación](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols) :) Y ¿cuáles son los mensajes de error? Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Lee por [aquí](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html). Esos símbolos son parte de kotlin como solución al manejo de los nullables.